# How to pass constants using a .idl file directly?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ros2 eloquent and trying to write a .idl message directly so that it could be compatible with Fast-DDS; I'm trying to pass constants in the .idl file. The file I wrote looks like

```
module package_name{
    module idl {
        struct exmaple_msg{
            // constants
           uint32 CONSTANT = 0;
       };
   };
};
```

I failed to pass it through rosidl_generate_interfaces; Could you give an correct syntax to write it and how to use it later ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356700/how-to-pass-constants-using-a-.idl-file-directly-?/) by [Jeremy_z](https://answers.ros.org/users/56498/jeremy_z/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-07-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-07-10**:
I would suggest to create a `.msg` file with just a constant and after building the package look at / copy the generated `.idl` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look under Constants of this link https://mhanckow.students.wmi.amu.edu.pl/corba/IDL.html#281057

I think you have to use `const` before the constant like in C++.

Also this is an example of what rosidl_generate_interfaces generates:

ROS2 ConstTest.msg:

```
uint8 CONST1=1
uint8 CONST2=2
uint8 CONST3=3

uint8 data
```

ConstTest.idl:

```
module package_name {
  module msg {
    module ConstTest_Constants {
      const uint8 FAILSAFE_MODE1 = 1;
      const uint8 FAILSAFE_MODE2 = 2;
      const uint8 FAILSAFE_MODE3 = 3;
    };
    struct ConstTest {
      uint8 data;
    };
  };
};
```

---

Originally posted by [MrCheesecake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44078/mrcheesecake/) with karma: 272 on 2020-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1